# git how others could use my local as remote

Tags: git, local

how some of my teammates could pull from my local. Let's say we are two. We don't want to push to the origin, we just want to work for some time as each of us is a remote for the other. So I want to keep working with the origin, but want to subscribe my local as a remote for the teammates, so they could pull/push from it, without going through the shared bare origin repo.

Comment: I think it breaks sane use of git. Why don't you create remote branch and do there whatever you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add each other as a remote, for example via a network share.
See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes for how to work with remotes and http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols for how to add a "local share" (If you mount Windows Network Shares, for example).